# Request for help fetching data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I keep track of certain stocks and I like to know what analyst price targets are out there for them.  There are two different sites which I regularly use: finviz and marketwatch.  So, if I want to know what the average analyst price is for stock AAPL, I would type:

marketwatch - http://custom.gtm.idmanagedsolutions.com/custom/ibg/html-analyst.asp?symb=aapl

finviz - http://elite.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i15

As you might expect the search query remains the same but just the ticker ("AAPL" here) changes.

What I am looking to do is figure out a way to have excel automatically/in the background periodically update the target prices listed on these pages for the stocks I track. Something like:

```
   A     |   B      |   C        
ticker     mktw PT    finviz PT 
AAPL         XX           YY
GOOG         XX           YY
NFLX         XX           YY
AMZN         XX           YY
```

The easy part seems to be having excel lookup the website for each stock since as I mentioned above the ticker remains static except for the ticker symbol. The hard part is how to have excel find and pull the data on the page (the analyst price target) I'm looking for.

As a starting point, I figure something along the lines of the below can be used to pull the data; but I dont know how to go about parsing the end result. I'm also doubtful that the approach below is efficient, it seems really intensive and I imagine there are more streamlined measures available.

```
Option Explicit
Sub get_data()
Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myURL = "http://custom.gtm.idmanagedsolutions.com/custom/ibg/html-analyst.asp?symb=aapl"

winHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
winHttpReq.Send
result = winHttpReq.responseText
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Range("Sheet1!A1").Value = result
End Sub
```

Is there a quick and dirty way to pull this off in excel?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will place the average target price for marketwatch and finviz in cells A1 and A2 of sheet1.  You could put this in a loop and capture the data for all of your stocks.

```
Sub get_data()
Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String

    For x = 1 To 2
      myURL = Choose(x, "http://custom.gtm.idmanagedsolutions.com/custom/ibg/html-analyst.asp?symb=aapl", "http://elite.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i15")
      Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
      Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

      xml_obj.Open "GET", myURL, False
      xml_obj.send
      html_doc.body.innerhtml = xml_obj.responseText
      Set xml_obj = Nothing

      If x = 1 Then
        Set Results = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each itm In Results
          If itm.className = "mwSmall" And InStr(1, itm.innerhtml, "Average Target Price:", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
              mktw_pt = Trim(itm.nextSibling.innertext)
              Exit For
          End If
        Next itm
      Else
        Set Results = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each itm In Results
          If itm.className = "snapshot-td2-cp" And InStr(1, itm.outerhtml, "Target Price", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
              finviz_pt = itm.nextSibling.innertext
              Exit For
          End If
        Next itm
      End If
    Next x

    Range("Sheet1!A1").Value = mktw_pt
    Range("Sheet1!A2").Value = finviz_pt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, when I try to run the code I get this error:



    Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)':

    Access is denied.


When I hit debug, the code highlights "xml_obj.send"


Doing a quick google search it seems like this is a permissions issue. I recently reformatted my computer and I've been having a lot of problems that end up being related to incorrect permissions.  I will try to run this code on my work computer and let you know how it turns out.  Thanks again.

Comment: See if this helps, IE-Tools-Internet Options-Security-Internet-Custom Level-Miscellaneous-set "Access data sources across domains" to "Enable" to prevent "Access Denied" errors.

Comment: Ron, I finally had a chance to reformat my computer to fix my permissions issue and your code (and your IE fix...) worked like an absolute charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: Incidentally, I am not at all a coder and so I'm not really sure how to code the loop through multiple tickers.  Assume I  have a cell with 20-40 tickers in it in cell C1 of would something along the lines of this work?

Dim ticker as string
Dim mytickers as range

mytickers = worksheet.cells.c1.value

For Each ticker in mytickers

[your code]

End If

Would something like that be the right approach?

Comment: Yes, a loop like that should work.  If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, thanks.